# Différentes sortes de "dédicaces"

Tags: grammaire, vocabulaire, prépositions, syntaxe

Il semble que le mot "dédicace" désigne de manière ambigüe deux choses différentes :

1. Des mots imprimés au début d'un livre pour rendre hommage à quelqu'un.
2. Des mots écrits à la main par l'auteur du livre au revers de la couverture d'un seul exemplaire d'un livre destinés à être lus par une seule personne.
   Y a-t-il d'autres mots ou expressions permettant de distinguer ces deux significations? Pour le 2), je vois éventuellement "une dédicace manuscrite"?
3. Enfin, lorsqu'on offre un livre, celui qui offre le livre peut écrire aussi quelques mots au revers de la couverture à destination de celui qui reçoit le livre : est-ce encore une "dédicace"? Si oui, comment le distinguer du sens ci-dessus? Pour être précis, faut-il dire "une dédicace manuscrite de l'auteur"? Et pour le 3) ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Toutes trois sont des dédicaces.

Pour distinguer la première, on pourra dire que le livre est **dédié** à une ou plusieurs personnes par l'auteur.

Pour la deuxième, on dira que le livre a été **dédicacé** par l'auteur à quelqu'un. Ce dernier peut recevoir le livre dédicacé en cadeau mais le plus souvent, il s'agit d'un inconnu qui aura d'abord acheté l'ouvrage puis demandé à l'auteur une dédicace. La dédicace est toujours signée.

Pour la troisième, le livre a été offert à quelqu'un de précis. On dira plutôt, untel a **écrit une dédicace** à l'attention d'untel/unetelle. La dédicace est alors souvent plus personnelle puisque le destinataire est connu de l'auteur de la dédicace qui n'est pas l'auteur du livre. Cette dédicace n'est pas forcément signée.

Je ne vois pas de moyen simple de distinguer ces divers cas en dehors des verbes utilisés et d'explications comme ci-dessus (nom de l'auteur du livre, de l'auteur de la dédicace, du destinataire, contexte de la dédicace).

Comment: Je t'ai dédié un +1.

Answer (score 2):

Caveat emptor: je réponds à la question du verbe dédicacer et les prépositions qui vont avec.  D'un point de vue descriptif, le chanteur [Pierpoljak](https://fr.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pierpoljak) qui vient de Paris a écrit les paroles suivantes (de *10 millions de glandeurs, Pierpoljak* 1996, l'emphase en gras c'est le mien).  Ça montre la langue parlée et la francophonie du monde.

> Écoute celle-la, elle vient du fond de mon coeur,  
> Elle est **dédicacée
> pour** tous les voyageurs, tous les glandeurs, 
> Tous les crotales, toutes
> les mygales 
> Actif, inactif, dans la ville ou à la campagne

[YouTube](https://youtu.be/JipqGu6ZNAM)

Peut-être c'est un anglicisme emprunté après avoir passé son adolescence à Londres à l'époque punk lorsqu'il a commencé à faire partie d'une communauté jamaïcaine de la musique reggae. Où peut-être après avoir passé des années au bord de la mer des Caraïbes, son sociolecte reflète son environnement très riche sur le plan linguistique (comme tout le monde).

En tout cas, une chanson **dédicacée pour** quelqu'un ou quelque chose, ça se dit. [Ngrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=D%C3%A9dicac%C3%A9%20%C3%A0%2C%20d%C3%A9dicac%C3%A9%20pour&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=fr-2019&smoothing=3) montre beaucoup plus souvent *dédicacé à* que *dédicacé pour*. Ce n'est pas une prescription mais ça fait partie de la langue.